# Lodsb assembly command syntax: what does GS: mean?

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86

I saw somewhere the command `gs:lodsq`. Now, from what that i understand, there is no such assembly command, the command `lodsb/w/q` should be alone on its line.

I searched the internet and looked in the instructions set but found no explanation. So my question is, what does it mean?

Comment: @rcgldr isn't the default segment register `ds`? `ss` is the stack segment

Comment: @jghfun-run - correct, default is ds. On some systems, gs is used to access per thread variables.

Comment: @rcgldr alright cool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It's almost certainly `lodsq` with a GS segment-override prefix**, overriding the implicit source from `RSI` (or `DS:RSI`) to `GS:RSI`.

It does the same thing as AT&T syntax `mov %gs:(%rsi), %rax` / `add $8, %rsi` or NASM syntax `mov rax, [gs:rsi]` / `add rsi,8`.  (Or sub depending on the direction flag).  But without clobbering flags, like LEA.

(In 32-bit mode, the implicit source defaults to `ds:esi`, but in 64-bit mode the DS segment base is fixed at `0` so Intel only describes it as `RSI` in [the official docs for `lods`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/LODS:LODSB:LODSW:LODSD:LODSQ.html))

---

**BTW, in AT&T syntax, `gs:lodsq` parses as `gs:` being a label name**, and `lodsq` simply being the instruction.

```
0000000000000000 <gs>:
   0:   48 ad                   lods   rax,QWORD PTR ds:[rsi]
```

In NASM syntax, YASM and NASM both treat it as an error.

```
# from yasm -felf64 foo.asm
foo.asm:1: error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `:'
```

The OP tried with MASM and it's an error there, too.

So perhaps it's FASM syntax, or a less-popular assembler, or maybe someone wrote this on a web page without actually trying it and got the syntax wrong.

---

The syntax for `lodsq` with a GS prefix varies by assembler:

GAS with AT&T or `.intel_syntax noprefix`:  **`gs lodsq`**, and `objdump -d` disassembles it as:

```
65 48 ad                lods   rax,QWORD PTR gs:[rsi]   # -Mintel
65 48 ad                lods   %gs:(%rsi),%rax          # -Matt
```

**NASM: also `gs lodsq`**.  That's how `ndisasm` disassembles it.

Comment: Thank's. But why when i tried to compile it the compiler didn't understand that?

Comment: @שמואלביאליסטוקי: where did you find this source line?  It may be MASM syntax or maybe FASM.  It's not NASM or AT&T.

Comment: The compiler i tried compile with was masm. I saw that you edit the answer so it explain that. Thank you very mach.

Comment: @שמואלביאליסטוקי Oh does MASM not accept it either?  Where did you find this?  Maybe someone wrote it by hand as an example without testing, and got the syntax wrong.  Or else it's in some other syntax.

Comment: Yha. It could really be as you say.

Comment: I suspect it is the way a particular disassembler (probably IDA Pro)  represents it. In MASM you do segment overrides on string instructions with something like `lodsq gs:[rsi]`